# Can't reduce size Realm adds to app

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to encourage the startup I work for to switch from SQLite to Realm. The biggest objection is how large it makes the app. The compiled release APK jumps from 3.5MB to 7.5MB after Realm (a 4MB difference). Post-installation size on a physical device seems to vary, but roams around 19MB on a Nexus 6P (a 6MB difference vs the SQLite version) and 16MB on the Nexus 5.

This seems substantially larger than the Realm docs indicate I should expect, but there seems to be little I can do. I tried the APK split as documented at https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#how-big-is-the-realm-library, but when I run the gradlew installDebug command, I get these errors:

```
Skipping device 'Nexus 5 - 5.1.1' for 'app:release': Could not find build of variant which supports density 480 and an ABI in armeabi-v7a, armeabi
Skipping device 'Nexus 6P - 6.0.1' for 'app:release': Could not find build of variant which supports density 560 and an ABI in arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, armeabi
```

Is there a way to get the APK split working, so only the native code for the given device's processor is needed,or is there anything else I can do to get the APK size down? I realize this isn't a huge, huge size impact as far as things go, but it concerns my superiors, and adding 50% to the size of an app is pretty substantial.

Build.gradle file, in case it helps:

```
// Manifest version information!
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0     // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    def globalConfiguration = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")

    compileSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidCompileSdkVersion")
    buildToolsVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidBuildToolsVersion")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gane"
        minSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidMinSdkVersion")
        targetSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidTargetSdkVersion")
        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    lintOptions {
        quiet true
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true
        disable 'InvalidPackage'            //Some libraries have issues with this.
        disable 'OldTargetApi'
        //Lint gives this warning but SDK 20 would be Android L Beta.
        disable 'IconDensities'             //For testing purpose. This is safe to remove.
        disable 'IconMissingDensityFolder'  //For testing purpose. This is safe to remove.
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
        }

        release {
            storeFile file('matrix')
            storePassword KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias 'matrix'
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-debug'

            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            // build.gradle testCoverageEnabled true causes debugger to be unable to view local variables/watches
            // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93730
            // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=123771
            testCoverageEnabled false
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            testCoverageEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        alpha.initWith(buildTypes.release)
        alpha {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }

        beta.initWith(buildTypes.release)
        beta {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'arm', 'arm-v7a', 'arm64', 'mips', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def appDependencies = rootProject.ext.appDependencies
    def appTestDependencies = rootProject.ext.appTestDependencies

    compile appDependencies.supportAppCompact
    compile appDependencies.supportCardView
    compile appDependencies.supportDesign
    compile appDependencies.supportPercent
    compile appDependencies.supportCustomTabs

    apt appDependencies.daggerCompiler
    compile appDependencies.dagger
    compile appDependencies.butterKnife
    compile appDependencies.gson
    compile appDependencies.okHttp
    compile appDependencies.okHttpUrlConnection
    compile appDependencies.picasso
    compile appDependencies.rxJava
    compile appDependencies.rxAndroid
    provided appDependencies.javaxAnnotation

    provided appDependencies.autoValue
    apt appDependencies.autoValue

    compile(appDependencies.crashlytics) {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile(appDependencies.hapiTenantLibrary) {
        transitive = true
        exclude module: 'android'
        exclude module: 'gson'
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
        exclude module: 'okhttp-urlconnection'
        exclude module: 'rxjava'
    }

    testCompile appTestDependencies.junit
    testCompile appTestDependencies.hamcrest
    // Robolectric to help us test Android based components (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceivers, etc)
    testCompile(appTestDependencies.robolectric) {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    testCompile appTestDependencies.mockito
    testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3' // fixes issue on linux/mac
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def appName
    //Check if an applicationName property is supplied; if not use the name of the parent project.
    if (project.hasProperty("applicationName")) {
        appName = applicationName
    } else {
        appName = parent.name
    }

    if (variant.buildType.name != "debug" && variant.outputs.zipAlign) {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def timestamp = new Date().format("yyyyMMdd-HHmm", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            def newApkName
            newApkName = "${appName}-${variant.versionName}-${timestamp}.apk"
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/redex

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#how-big-is-the-realm-library

Comment: @Abdellah: that might also be useful, but my goal here is to get Realm as small as the Realm documentation says I can

Comment: @geisshirt: yes, that is what I was linking to, when I was describing the instructions I followed to achieve the results described in my post. The problem is, those instructions are not working from me. Hopefully someone from Realm will help solve my problem. Thanks for providing the corrected link, as the anchor I was using was a couple lines above that section. I've updated the link in my post.

Comment: As I work for Realm, I'll happy to either help you or correct our documentation if it is inaccurate.

Comment: @geisshirt Yes, in that case, an answer to my posted question would be pretty awesome! :) Is there something I'm doing wrong? Why doesn't the APK split work for Nexus 5 or Nexus 6P?

Comment: @geisshirt Can you or someone from Realm answer the question? It would be awesome to get this working! :)

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file? It looks like you're doing splits both on ABI and pixel density. Does removing the split on density help?

Comment: @Emanuelez Nope, just a split on the ABI, exactly as the Realm docs describe. But their APK split does not seem to allow for all processor types, including those used by the Nexus 5 and Nexus 6P.  Realm says StackOverflow is their main avenue of tech support, but four days later I still have no answer from them :(

Comment: Actually both @geisshirt and I work for Realm :)
I'm still curious to see your `gradle.build` file. We provide binaries for ARM, ARMv7a, ARM64, MIPS, x86 and x86-64 so I'm sure both the Nexus 5 (ARMv7a) and Nexus6P (ARM64) are supported if you provide the proper configuration in Gradle.

Comment: What if you enable the lint warning regarding pixel density and fix the resulting issues? Does that help? I suspect the issue here is about pixel density and not Realm itself.

Comment: Gradle file posted in https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2649 . What's the lint warning regarding pixel density? I'm not familiar with that lint check. I can't imagine why it would have anything to do with that--especially as when using the new APK split code, I just get the "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113" error. I can't find any mention in the output of pixel density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was apparently twofold:

1. The APK split information did not include builds for Nexus devices. Realm has updated their documentation, so that is resolved.
2. My Gradle file had an added section to rename the APK files.

Now the APK split works, which makes the APK a manageable size.